# fastest way to delete columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix of size 139 X 143896.

I have to delete 6000 columns from it.

Currently I am using a for loop to do it and it is really slow.

Is there any faster way to do this?

```
for i=1:length(ind)
   %ind are the indices of the columns to be removed
   col1=ind(i);
   mat(:,col1)=[];
end
```

Any help is greatly welcome.

Comment: Not only is that slow, you might be removing the wrong columns, since every time you loop you are changing the size of `mat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete them in one go -

```
mat(:,ind)=[];
```